# Laravel error: symlink() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, laravel-5, symlink

I'm trying to set-up a laravel cms system that already exists on a shared host. But when i setup my laravel project on this shared hosting directory i get the error
**symlink() has been disabled for security reasons**
I can't seem to find a proper explenation on how i can fix this in my situation. I only get this error the first time and when i refresh this error, it disappears.
[image: Error message]

Comment: hosting issue. the function `symlink()` is disabled, that's why it cannot be called. You need to enable it via php.ini or use a proper host.

Comment: how to enable it in php.ini

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 options to solve this;

1. Use any of the supported services for file storage i.e Amazon S3, Dropbox, FTP, Rackspace
2. Follow the steps below;
   Create a folder in **/public** folder named **/storage**
   Move all folders from /storage/app/public/ to the folder you created **/public/storage/**
   Open file **config/filesystems.php** and change the values as shown;

   ```
    'local'     => [
       'driver' => 'local',
       'root'   => public_path('storage'),
   ],

   'public'    => [
       'driver'     => 'local',
       'root'       => public_path('storage'),
       'url'        => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
       'visibility' => 'public',
   ],
   ```

Now open file **.env** and change or create the values as shown below;

```
AVATAR_DIR=avatars
SIGNATURE_DIR=signatures
LOGOS_DIR=logos
MEDIA_DIR=media
```

Answer (score 2):

in your project's public directory, manually create a *storage* folder.

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can create symlink for your desired directory by logging in to your server via SSH download [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) and then login to your server via putty by using your server credentials. You can use linux commands to create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME
```

Where the -s makes it symbolic.

Comment: In my case the php code wasn't able to create symlink so i tried it using sssh

Answer (score 1):

After a lot struggle this trick work for me at shared hosting server for **Laravel** project.

1. Connect with terminal at server via SSH or directly from CPanel
2. Run this command at your terminal

   `ln -s /folder-path-with-name-to-be-linked /folder-paht-where-you-want-to-link-it`

e.g in my case

`ln -s /home/user-name/public_html/domain-folder-name/storage/app/public /home/user-name/public_html/domain-folder/public/`

**Note:** You don't need to change in php.ini and .htaceess files.
**Reference Link:**
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141436/too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links/141442#141442?newreg=14b52f3d6fcb454399a1a1a66e2170df

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that your hosting provider will not let you create the smlink.Have you checked if this is the case? 
One suggestion if so, is to write the files that you would have put in the symlink folder  directly into the public area of the site so that a symlink is not required.